# How to create circular marks/buttons and circular window

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Let me try to explain what I am doing...

I am creating a map with some marks on the map, but I want to change these marks to circular buttons. When I click, it should open a circular window over my map with some options (map in the background).

Is it possible?
If my explanation is not clear I can paste my code. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

U can use an outline object with android L or u can set an oval background image (f.e. define a oval drawable file)

Here is some sample code:

```
   //Outline
    int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
    Outline outline = new Outline();
    outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
```

And some code example for an oval drawable:

```
<shape 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">

        <solid 
           android:color="#79bfea"/>
```

Comment: If you share some code for OP then it will be sure helpful to him.

Comment: Nice! Have fun with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a XML file inside your res/Drawable

round_button.xml

```
<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <stroke android:color="#ffffff" />  

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And in your component xml set the background:

```
 android:background="@drawable/round_button"
```